# Text Mining - Similarity among words to determine thresholds

Tags: r, text-mining

While trying to find how one place (Military High School) like a school is similar to another one (Military H School or Military High S), I used the LV algorithm to find the string distance and then converted them into a percentage on a calibrated scale.

stringdist(data[i,1],data[i,2],method = "lv")

Though this is admissible, I still need a more precise way to determine the threshold. The goal is to set a threshold of acceptance for a variation of a name from the standardized name, so that say if the threshold of this word is less than say 85%, it would be rejected. This exercise is part of data pre-processing.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [word2vec](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/word2vec/index.html) models ?. One of the main application is computing similar words, as they are very closer in the feature vector space. Thus apart from `High_school` and `H_school`, also `secondary_school`, `public_school` may also be obtained as closer words. The important thing is that a huge amount of sentences are needed for this unsupervised learning model.

Ref: [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html), [word2vec in java](https://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec)

Answer (score 1):

In order to optimize the string distance threshold for maximizing classification accuracy in your data, if you don't already have a **gold standard** dataset, you will want to label some of your data. Depending on your situation, this could be as easy as you yourself hand-labeling string pairs as *same* or *notsame*. If you need more robust data, you would obviously want to use several labelers and use some sort of procedure to ensure high inter-coder reliability (I discuss this at length under **data quality** in this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12265/categorizing-customer-emails/12268#12268)).

Next, compute string distance as before on this data. Create a vector of threshold values, e.g., `thresholds <- seq(from = 0, to = 20, by = 1)`, then for each threshold compute your performance metrics on your labeled data set (e.g., accuracy, precision, recall). Choose the threshold that maximizes your desired metric.